# Delete Node on Update in DB

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on user mgmt part here I have created Form for Funder so my form looks  some what like the below .
 I'm using this Form for **Create Funder** and **Update Funder**, Now the Problem is in *Update* *Part*. 
 When Funder tries to delete *POC NODE* or *BENF Node* or *Location Node* on **UI** the same should be Reflected on **DB** After Submitting Form.
Similar to **Delete** before there was problem in adding of *LOC,BENF* and *POC*, if user add *Benf,LOC or POC Nodes* in **UI** and then click on Update button  it should reflect the same in **DB** table of *LOC,BENF and POC* 
so my Query for this was Simple **UPDATE** Query *before* but after this problem i made it  ***INSERT INTO ON ... DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE..*** 
(Note: I'll be saving all Data on Form Submission)
Now if user delete *Benf,LOC or POC Nodes* in **UI** and then click on Update button  it should reflect the same in **DB** table of *LOC,BENF and POC*?

```
    __ __ __ __ __ __
   |Funder Form      |
   |  --Field1       |
   |  --Field2       |
   |  --Field3       |
   |__ __ __ __ __ __|

  Add Benef    +
________________________
    __ __ __ __ __ __
   |Benf Form      - |
   |  --Field1       |
   |  --Field2       |
   |  --Field3       |
   |__ __ __ __ __ __|   

  Add Location    +
________________________
    __ __ __ __ __ __
   |Location Form  - |
   |  --Field1       |
   |  --Field2       |
   |  --Field3       |
   |                 |
   | Add POC     +   |
   |________________ |
   |POC Form     -   |
   |  --Field1       |
   |  --Field2       |
   |  --Field3       |      
   |__ __ __ __ __ __|   
   __________________
  |   UPDATE         |
  |__________________|
```